# Making pandas dataframe by using strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

Hello everyone,

I tried to make dataframe column "Date" and add datetimes to the column rows. The datetime appears every 5th time in the string list.

I think something method like range(start,end,step) would be good but how it will be done in practice?

Here is my code:

```
import requests, re, pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&statsfilter=2816&offset=0")
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")


for string in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"covSmallHeadline"})[6:]:
    print(string.text.replace("(","").replace(")",""))
```

and here is the output (real list size is bigger):

```
5/3 17
 Astralis 16
 FaZe 13
inferno
IEM Katowice 2017
5/3 17
 Astralis 16
 FaZe 12
nuke
IEM Katowice 2017
5/3 17
 Astralis 16
 FaZe 12
overpass
IEM Katowice 2017
5/3 17
 FaZe 16
 Astralis 9
cache
IEM Katowice 2017
4/3 17
 Astralis 16
 Heroic 12
nuke
IEM Katowice 2017
4/3 17
 Astralis 16
 Heroic 12
train
IEM Katowice 2017
4/3 17
 Immortals 10
 FaZe 16
mirage
IEM Katowice 2017
4/3 17
 FaZe 16
 Immortals 9
inferno
IEM Katowice 2017
3/3 17
 Natus Vincere 2
 Astralis 16
nuke
IEM Katowice 2017
```

Comment: Could you please clarify which kind of output (DataFrame, Series) you want to get from the input? This isn't clear to me right now.

Comment: I tried to make pandas.DataFrame output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert data to CSV first:

```
import re
In [83]: for row in table.find_all('div', style=re.compile(r'width:606px;height:22px;background-color')):
   ...:      print(row.get_text(strip=True, separator=','))


5/3 17,Astralis (16),FaZe (13),inferno,IEM Katowice 2017
5/3 17,Astralis (16),FaZe (12),nuke,IEM Katowice 2017
5/3 17,Astralis (16),FaZe (12),overpass,IEM Katowice 2017
```

Comment: I would ask because of learning, what this line: 'width:606px;height:22px;background-color' actually does?

Comment: @Juho M It's the style attribute, I located each row using this string. Because each row's style is different, so I use `re` to match their same part.https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression